# Is there any reference in the Quran (or any other Islamic Literature) about the divinity of humans as referenced in Psalms 82:6?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, islamic-basis, christianity, judaism, divine-attributes

In the TaNaK/Christian old testament there is a Psalm that references the children of The Supreme One/Most High GOD as being divine:

> Psalms 82:6  אֲנִי-אָמַרְתִּי, אֱלֹהִים אַתֶּם;    וּבְנֵי עֶלְיוֹן כֻּלְּכֶם.    6 I said: Ye are godlike beings, and all of you sons of the Most High.

Yahshua/Jesus/Isa also used as a reference in The Brit Chadasha/Christian New Testament:

> John 10:34-36: 34 Jesus answered them, Is it not written in your law,
> I said, Ye are gods?
>
> 35 If he called them gods, unto whom the word of God came, and the
> scripture cannot be broken;
>
> 36 Say ye of him, whom the Father hath sanctified, and sent into the
> world, Thou blasphemest; because I said, I am the Son of God?

It is also mentioned in the Gospel of John as Christ's ability to be a vessel to give access to those who following his teachings, to also become Divine:

> John 1:12 But as many as received him, to them gave he power to become the sons of God, even to them that believe on his name

Now I want to make clear when I write/mention divine is not to be confused as proclaiming to being or becoming The Supreme One/The Most High GOD themselves but Divine as a means of elevating and becoming one/connecting/knowing/being intimate with The Supreme One/Most High GOD.  Is there an equivalent scripture/passage referenced in the Quran or in any commentaries/literature within the Islamic Faith? Thank you, Peace, and Blessings to you.

Comment: It could be helpful if you shared the content of corresponding quotes instead of linking them.

Comment: Sure no problem

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such reference in the Qur'an/Hadith, to my knowledge.

The very idea of being "godlike" is problematic from an Islamic standpoint. The Qur'an contains various verses that make it clear that God is unlike any of His creation.

> Qur'an 42:11 فاطر السماوات والأرض جعل لكم من أنفسكم أزواجا ومن الأنعام أزواجا يذرؤكم فيه ليس كمثله شيء وهو السميع البصير  ([He is] Creator of the heavens and the earth. He has made for you from yourselves, mates, and among the cattle, mates; He multiplies you thereby. **There is nothing like unto Him**, and He is the Hearing, the Seeing)

Moreover, Allah (ﷻ) even dismisses the notion of "sons/children of God":

> Qur'an 5:18 وقالت اليهود والنصارى نحن أبناء الله وأحباؤه قل فلم يعذبكم بذنوبكم بل أنتم بشر ممن خلق يغفر لمن يشاء ويعذب من يشاء ولله ملك السماوات والأرض وما بينهما وإليه المصير  (And (both) the Jews and the Christians say: "We are the children of Allah and His loved ones." Say: "Why then does He punish you for your sins?" **Nay, you are but human beings**, of those He has created, He forgives whom He wills and He punishes whom He wills. And to Allah belongs the dominion of the heavens and the earth and all that is between them, and to Him is the return (of all))

Islam is very clear that humans are just creations of God, nothing more. Even the best of humanity and leader of the Prophets, Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ), has never been attributed with anything other than being a [non-divine] regular man. Allah (ﷻ) commanded him to say and affirm to the people:

> Quran 18:110 قل إنما أنا بشر مثلكم يوحى إلي أنما إلهكم إله واحد فمن كان يرجو لقاء ربه فليعمل عملا صالحا ولا يشرك بعبادة ربه أحدا  (**Say, "I am only a man like you**, to whom has been revealed that your god is one God. So whoever would hope for the meeting with his Lord - let him do righteous work and not associate in the worship of his Lord anyone.")

On the other hand, what you describe of "connecting/knowing/being intimate with The Supreme One/Most High GOD" is definitely possible. Prophet Abraham (peace be upon him) had the title of Khalil-Allah (Friend of God).

> Qur'an 4:125 ومن أحسن دينا ممن أسلم وجهه لله وهو محسن واتبع ملة إبراهيم حنيفا واتخذ الله إبراهيم خليلا  And who is better in religion than one who submits himself to Allah while being a doer of good and follows the religion of Abraham, inclining toward truth? And **Allah took Abraham as an intimate friend**.

Islam teaches us that we can come closer and closer to Allah (ﷻ) until we become His 'Wali' which is a pious worshiper who is his close friend. Anyone has potential to reach this level through piety and righteous deeds.

> Qur'an 10:62 ألا إن أولياء الله لا خوف عليهم ولا هم يحزنون  (Behold! verily **on the friends of Allah** there is no fear, nor shall they grieve)

In conclusion, there is no concept of "divine humans" nor any concept of being "children of God" but there is a concept of being close/intimate Friends of God (Awliya).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Peace and Divine Blessings beloved.  I appreciate you taking the time to respond and give an answer to my inquiry.  I would like to mention that Psalms 82:6 also has a connection and reference to Genesis 1:26: And God said, Let us make man in our image, after our likeness: and let them have dominion over the fish of the sea, and over the fowl of the air, and over the cattle, and over all the earth, and over every creeping thing that creepeth upon the earth....Do you know of a similar reference in the Quran or how is man's creation and purpose interpreted from an Islamic point of view?

Comment: Also, I would upvote your answer but I do not have the "credentials" to do so as of yet :)

Comment: There is a hadith which says Adam was created in Allah's (ﷻ) image. You can read an explanation about it here: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/20652/commentary-on-the-hadeeth-allaah-created-adam-in-his-image

Comment: As for man's purpose, Allah (ﷻ) said in Qur'an 51:56 وما خلقت الجن والإنس إلا ليعبدون (And I did not create the jinn and mankind except to worship Me)

Comment: No worries about upvotes :)